# What is the correct way to use Tab View scrollable property?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, node-modules, primeng

I am using p-tabview and I want to implement scrollable property as stated in primeng site: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/tabview

But I am getting an error stating Can't bind to 'scrollable' since it isn't a known property of 'p-tabView'. Am I missing anything?

StackBlitz demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tabview-demo-jj9f2g?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Reference code:

```
<div class="card">
 <h5>Default</h5>
 <p-tabView [scrollable]="true">
 <p-tabPanel header="Header 1"> Content 1 </p-tabPanel>
 <p-tabPanel header="Header 2"> Content 2 </p-tabPanel>
 <p-tabPanel header="Header 3"> Content 3 </p-tabPanel>
 <p-tabPanel header="Header 3"> Content 3 </p-tabPanel>
 </p-tabView>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue was fixed lately at
https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/10119

So you need to use primeng version 12.1.1 or above